# Trying to copy data from one sheet to another and creating multiple entries

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with the following worksheets Activity List - 1 column containing a variable list of Activities (String Data) Template - This sheet contains a 7 column X 22 row group of cell that comprise a template used on the next sheet. Activity Steps - This sheet contains The completed Templates Listed down the screen with 1 blank line between them.

My goal is to create the Activity Steps Sheet automatically. To do this I first find the number of rows in the Activity List Sheet. Then Copy the Activity (the string on the first cell of the Activity List) to the first cell of the Template. I will also copy the same string to another cell in the template. Then I want to copy the Range that contains the Completed Template to the Activity Steps sheet. Leaving a blank line between the previous one.

I have tried most of the code below as single sections but when I try to put it together as a single routine I get a "Runtime error 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error"
I need help figuring out how to make it work.

Thanks

```
Sub Create_Activity()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Activity Steps") 'declare and set your worksheet

With Worksheets("Activity List") 'Count the number of rows in Activity List NbrOfActivities = Application.Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count End With

For i = 1 To NbrOfActivities

Activity = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Activity List").Cells(i, 1).Value 'Get First Activity From List
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Cells(A, 1).Value = Activity 'Put Activity into Cell A1 on Template
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Cells(D, 4).Value = Activity 'Put Activity into Cell D4 on Template
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("A1:G23").Copy 'Copy Complet Template Range
NextRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 2 'Get next Row in Activity Steps workSheet

ws.Range("A" & NextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'paste completed template in Activity Steps worksheet
Next i ' Get next Activity From List

End Sub
```

Comment: What line gives the error?

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Cells(A, 1).Value = Activity 'Put Activity into Cell A1 on Template

Comment: `Cells(A, 1)` --> `Cells(1, "A")`. Similarly, `Cells(D, 4)` -->`Cells(4, "D")`.

Comment: Thanks that was it.  Thanks